# Cyclically iterating through C++ map, program crashes

Tags: c++

I am new to SO.  I am new to iterators (or rather STL) in C++.  I am trying to iterate through the keys of a map in a cyclic manner.  So, we start reading from the start, proceed onto the end, and then go back to the start again.  The code below is a simplification of the relevant portion of my program:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    map<const char*, int> colors;

    colors  = { {     "RED", 1 },
                {  "YELLOW", 2 },
                {   "GREEN", 3 },
                {  "ORANGE", 4 },
                {    "CYAN", 5 } };

    map<const char*, int>::iterator itr = colors.begin();
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)        // Loop more than entries in map
    {
        cout<<itr->first<<endl;

        if(itr==colors.end())
            itr = colors.begin();  //start from beginning
        else
            itr++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My program (and the above program) keeps crashing after iterating through the map once.  I am not able to figure out why.  I tried looking up on SO and elsewhere and couldn't find a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about what the iterator points to for each go around the loop.

When the iterator becomes equal to `colors.end()`, it doesn't point to anything and you're not allowed to dereference it.

But you dereference the iterator (`itr->first`) *before* you check whether it is equal to `colors.end()`.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot that end() points to nothing, rather than the last entity in the container.  I am embarrassed.

Answer (score 0):

See comments:

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    std::cout << itr->first << std::endl;//Problematic..
    if(itr == colors.end())
        itr = colors.begin();  
    else
        itr++;                           //If this increment results to an `end()` iterator  
}
```

You are **unconditionally** accessing the iterator without checking if it's an `end()` iterator. You should check that the iterator isn't an `end()` iterator before you access the element it points to.

You can change your loop to:

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){        // Loop more than entries in map
    if( itr != colors.end() ){
        std::cout<< itr->first << std::endl;
        ++itr;
    }
    else
         itr = colors.begin();  //start from beginning
}
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/238075d9a06cf567)